# Image File Upload and Retrieve in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to build an application in Electron which has a html form with image Upload button. So my purpose is to ask the user to upload an image and  i want to save the image file somewhere in the local folder within the app and retrieve the  image whenever i need.How would i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you intend to store the image on the user's computer so there's no need to do a remote upload. You simply have to copy the file from its original location to the application local data path.

To achieve this, you could add to your form a button which would first trigger a [dialog](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialog) to let the user browse for the file.
Then you would [copy](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback) the chosen file to your application [local data path](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname).
After that, the idea would be to store some information about the image file so that you can retrieve it for later use.

```
const { app, dialog } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");

// The function triggered by your button
function storeImageFile() {

  // Open a dialog to ask for the file path
  const filePath = dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile'] })[0];
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

  // Copy the chosen file to the application's data path
  fs.copyFile(filePath, (app.getPath('userData') + fileName), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Image ' + fileName + ' stored.');

    // At that point, store some information like the file name for later use
  });
}
```

Comment: i am getting the following error- The "path" argument must be of type string.

Comment: i have solved it by modifying the following line - const filePath = dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile'] }).toString()

Comment: I missed the fact that it returned a `String[]` even for a single file selection, so you simply have to append `[0]` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer:

> The **dialog.showOpenDialog()** returns a promise

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { dialog } = electron;    // electron.remote; (if in renderer process)
const fs = require('fs');       // module that interacts with the file system
const path = require("path");   // utilities for working with directory paths

function uploadImageFile() {

    // opens a window to choose file
    dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile']}).then(result => {

        // checks if window was closed
        if (result.canceled) {
            console.log("No file selected!")
        } else {

            // get first element in array which is path to file selected
            const filePath = result.filePaths[0];

            // get file name
            const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

            // path to app data + fileName = "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\app_name\picture.png"
            imgFolderPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), fileName);

            // copy file from original location to app data folder
            fs.copyFile(filePath, imgFolderPath, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(fileName + ' uploaded.');
            });
        }
    });
}

// click event to trigger upload function
// In html:  <input type="button" class="upload-image" value="Upload Image">

$(".upload-image").on("click", () => {
    uploadImageFile()
});
```